# Add Dynamic Check Box in Grid Takes Time in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I Have a Grid (BrkGrid) in ViewMode... I Add dynamic Check Box (brkChkBox) depending on some logic. A foreach is responsible for adding check boxes to a specific row and column of this grid.. But it takes time while adding check boxes to the BrkGrid.. When I Comment the Add Statement (BrkGrid.Children.Add(brkChkBox)) then the code executes faster.. Any help will be highly appreciated...

```
CheckBox brkChkBox = null;
foreach (var s in this.ViewData.PlnDtShiftBrksDateList)
{
    brkChkBox = new CheckBox
    {
        DataContext = s,
        Tag = s.BreakID,
        Width = 20,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
    };

    Binding chkBoxBinding = new Binding("IsSelected");
    chkBoxBinding.Source = s;
    chkBoxBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

    brkChkBox.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, chkBoxBinding);
    brkChkBox.Click += brkChkBox_Click;

    Grid.SetColumn(brkChkBox, gridColDic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == s.BreakID).Value);
    Grid.SetRow(brkChkBox, gridRowDic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.Date == s.Date.Date).Value);
    BrkGrid.Children.Add(brkChkBox);
}
```

Comment: I dont really understand what do you want here. Your code is ok and the amount of time it will take depends only on the amount of data you are using. What consumes times in foreach statement is how many items you have inside the collection you are accessing.Also, you have LinQ statements, which will consume time going through all the list before returning the desired item. Do you want to show the user that you are loading data? Is that the question?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Well the problem is that the line of code "BrkGrid.Children.Add(brkChkBox)" takes time while executing, but if i  add labels dynamically instead of Check Boxes, the code executes faster.